# How to activate PHP7.0 PDO in 16.04 LTS?

Tags: php7

I upgraded from 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS; php5 to php7.0; MySQL to 5.7. Apache and PHP are working but when trying to access MySQL databases, I get the following:

```
fatal error: could not find driver
```

phpinfo() shows "no value" under PDO Drivers Enabled. Tried to compare `php.ini` from PHP5 but couldn't see anything obvious. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Installing `php7.0-mysql` should be enough:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

You will then need to ensure the module is enabled:

```
sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql
```

Then restart Apache to load the new modules:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I am using nginx. Shall I follow same steps and then restart nginx ?

Comment: @VivekSadh On nginx you probably use php-fpm and therefore need to restart the php server: /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart

Comment: Yeah I figured it out that day. Thx!

Comment: works for php 7.2 too. sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql

Answer (score 2):

If the problem persists, do:

```
sudo apt install php7.0-sqlite3
```

Comment: E: Package 'php7.-0-sqlite3' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

Also try changing the file `core/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/response/sfWebResponse.class.php`.

You need to change `preg_replace` to `preg_replace_callback` for php7.0.

Answer (score 0):

For earlier versions:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-pdo
```